# How to replace the entire form with the $message?

Tags: php

I am new in php, so I need your help. 
At first I created two .php files. The first included a form and the second included the message.

I wish to replace the form to a message in the same page after submit.
how I do that?

```
<?php
  $message="";
  if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])) {
    $name= $_POST["name"];
    $age= $_POST["age"];
    $username= $_POST["username"];
    $message= "your name is ". $name. ",you are ".$age
    ." and your reddit's username is ".$username;
  }
 ?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>new file</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
    <form  action="" method="post">
    <table >
      <tr>
        <th>name:</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="name" >
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>age:</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="age" >
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>username:</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="username">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit"  value="click here for save" name="submitButton">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `form` in a conditional.

```
<?php
  $message= isset($_POST["submitButton"]) ? "your name is ". $_POST["name"]. ",you are ".$_POST["age"]
    ." and your reddit's username is ".$_POST["username"] : "";
 ?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>new file</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php if (!empty($message)) {
         echo $message; 
     } else { ?>
    <form  action="" method="post">
    <table >
      <tr>
        <th>name:</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="name" >
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>age:</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="age" >
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>username:</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="username">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit"  value="click here for save" name="submitButton">
  </form>
    <?php } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help.
I have another question for you, how can I minimize my code length?

Comment: Updated answer using ternary operator, php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php, for shorter PHP code. If you meant HTML get rid of the tables and use divs with some CSS. If this resolves your issue please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below given codes. empty() function Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

By using it in condition it can solve your problem.

```
    <?php
      $message="";
      if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])) {
        $name= $_POST["name"];
        $age= $_POST["age"];
        $username= $_POST["username"];
        $message= "your name is ". $name. ",you are ".$age
        ." and your reddit's username is ".$username;
      }
     ?>

    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>new file</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <?php 
          if (!empty($message)) {
             echo $message; 
          }else{
        ?>
        <form  action="" method="post">
        <table >
          <tr>
            <th>name:</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="name" >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>age:</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="age" >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>username:</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="username">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit"  value="click here for save" name="submitButton">
      </form>
      <?php } ?>
      </body>
```